# Is it sensible to turn off the phone for charging?

Tags: charging, battery-life, battery-saver

I know that electronic devices, when not in use for a few hours and especially when charging, should be turned off.
However, when I turn my phone off and plug it into the charger, it shows the "Unlocked Bootloader" warning before showing the charging status, meaning it turns itself on again somewhat.

Is the wear of that negligible, or would it make more sense to simply leave the phone on in battery saving/flight mode when charging overnight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not shut down the phone before charging because of two reasons:

1. Modern phones often have an optimized battery loading algorithm especially when charging over night. The charging speed is reduced and the last percent or charged the hour before you usually disconnect the phone from charger. Such an advanced loading strategy is usually not implemented in "charging OS" (the minimal OS started for charging).
2. Another reason is your power button. Turning the phone on usually requires the power button. Unfortunately this crucial button is often the part that fails first...